# How can app "know" which connection string to use based on whether it's in production or development server?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, deployment, environment-variables

I have an ASP.NET Core app that is deployed to a dev server and prod server, sequentially (deployed to IIS).

How can the app 'know' the server that it is currently deployed to so that it can use the right connection string to connect to the dev/prod sql server? Do I have to set an environment variable on each server and have the startup file check the value of it?

This is what I've read, but am not entirely sure this is the right process.

Comment: What you've read is more or less correct. What causes your hesitation? [The official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-7.0) is fairly thorough and clear on this topic, IMO

Comment: I'm new to the deployment side of the development cycle. You said more or less, is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're missing - only you can tell me that. I don't know what you've read or what you've tried. Read the docs I linked, and if you have specific questions not answered within, then ask those questions.

Comment: different environment should use different configuration file, for example in asp.net core project, we would have `appsettings.json` and `appsettings.Development.json`. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynq1s.png

Comment: @TinyWang I know that,  but how would the project know which file to use? I know if the env var in launchSettings is set to Development, then it defaults to appsettings.development.json, but when deployed to production, how would you change that variable programmatically?

Comment: I don't think we should change variable programmatically, we can manually modify the `"ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"` in `launchSetting.json`, or adding environment variable `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` in the server. You can refer to the link shared by @Luke.

Comment: I ended up doing the latter part you mentioned via web.config files anyway, since launchSettings.json isn’t deployed

Answer (score 1):

You should use both a appsettings.{Environment}.json and appsettings.json.
Values in the appsettings.{Environment}.json will override the appsettings.json.
The environment version of the file is loaded based on the IHostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName which reads from the DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT and ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variables which you can set in each deployment.
Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: Would these variables be set manually every time I want to deploy? This is what I’m confused about. Everywhere I read it seems like I have to change the settings or config files manually before deploying to production or staging. My thought was that this is supposed to be automated.

Comment: The setting of the environment variables can be scripted and run as part of your CI/CD pipeline or provisioning scripts, this is going to look different dependent on your infrastructure and how you are managing it. Where are you deploying your code and how are you deploying it?

Comment: We aren’t using Ci/CD and are deploying manually to IIS. We just have different web.config files on each environment server that have different aspnetcore_environment values.